# How to force every Browser to set the Form-Data to it's actual values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I'm currently writing a ToDo-Script for a project i have running.

Now there is some (in this case) annoying behavior of some Browsers (e.g. Firefox), they remember previous form data. This feature sure can be handy but if you write a ToDo-Script which relies on Checkboxes, it's simply annoying.

My problem is, that the Browser remembers the form data and sets the checked state as it was last time. This can be inaccurate (e.g. when multiple people are editing at the same time and a simple refresh doesn't do the job).

is there a way to set the actual checked state by the html attribute "checked" you get from the django template?

here is what I do in my django-template:

```
{% for t in todos %}
  <div class='todo_div'>
    {% if t.is_done %}
      <input type='checkbox' name='{{ t.pk }}' class='todo_checkbox' value='{{ t.pk }}' checked='true' />
    {% else %}
      <input type='checkbox' name='{{ t.pk }}' class='todo_checkbox' value='{{ t.pk }}'/>
    {% endif %}
    {{ t.text }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the

```
autocomplete="off"
```

attribute on your input but this is unreliable.

The best way is to randomize your form input names. Each time the form is rendered, you could generate a random string like "klsdjhfsdf". Then, name your input like this:

```
<input name="klsdjhfsdf-MyRealInputName" ...>
```

Server-side you parse the received inputs and look at everything after the first hyphen to get the input name.

Comment: Nice idea to use a random prefix! Since the OP is using Django, they can use the [form prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms) feature, and Django will handle the prefix automatically. The one change required is to use `<prefix>-name` with a hyphen instead of an underscore, so I've edited your answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `autocomplete` attribute to off in the sourrounding vorm element:

```
<form action="" method="" autocomplete="off">
  ...
  <input type='checkbox' name='{{ t.pk }}' class='todo_checkbox' value='{{ t.pk }}'/>
  ...
</form>
```

See the [MDN tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion) on this.

Answer (score 1):

You could attach a .submit() listener in which you set the contents of whatever form elements.

Somewhat like

```
$('#msgform').submit(function () {
    $('input[name=foo]').attr('checked', false);
});
```

if you're using jQuery.